# Last order openprice in MQL5

Tags: mql5, mql

I am new to MQL and struggling to find out how to get my last order (currently opened) price and the ticket number in MQL5. Can anyone help me with that?

To be honest I tried several things on internet but nothing worked for me. My simple expectation is to get the last opened price and ticket number and I want to use those information to generate a new order according to my strategy.

Comment: Hi. Did you try to Google this question? My first hit was this and looks exactly what you mean: https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/333343